# What's the most practical method to calculate Complex Dielectric Constant of Water?

Tags: electromagnetism, water, dielectric

I need to find the real part and imaginary part of Complex Dielectric Constant of Water, in calculation of ITU P.618-9 rain attenuation model. In my calculation using the model, the carrier frequency is **rougly 9GHz**,  rainfall temperature is set to **(273.15 + 23) Kelvin**.

I came accross [one online calculator of Complex Dielectric Constant of Water](https://www.random-science-tools.com/electronics/water_dielectric.htm). Its corresponding paper is ["The Complex Dielectric Constant of Pure and Sea Water from Microwave Satellite Observations" (2004)](https://images.remss.com/papers/ssmi/the_complex_dielectric_constant_of_pure_and_sea_water_from_microwave_satellite_observations.pdf).

---

My question is:

Is this method calcultaing Complex Dielectric Constant of Water reliable?

What's the most sophisticated and practical method to calculate Complex Dielectric Constant of Water in 2023?

Comment: Similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94639/dielectric-constant-of-water